# TypeError while running python webapp, what anamoly in python code could have caused it?

Tags: python, flask

I wrote the framework for a web app using python flask and PostgreSQL as the back end. It should allow one to submit text to be saved. But when I tried running it, I get the following TypeError:

> TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The
> function either returned None or ended without a return statement.

The traceback to the error page:

```
Traceback (most recent call last) File
"/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2464,
in call return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response) File
"/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2450,
in wsgi_app response = self.handle_exception(e) File
"/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1867,
in handle_exception reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb) File
"/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line
39, in reraise raise value File
"/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447,
in wsgi_app response = self.full_dispatch_request() File
"/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1953,
in full_dispatch_request return self.finalize_request(rv) File
"/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1968,
in finalize_request response = self.make_response(rv) File
"/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2097,
in make_response raise TypeError( TypeError: The view function did not
return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended
without a return statement. The debugger caught an exception in your
WSGI application. You can now look at the traceback which led to the
error. To switch between the interactive traceback and the plaintext
one, you can click on the "Traceback" headline. From the text
traceback you can also create a paste of it. For code execution
mouse-over the frame you want to debug and click on the console icon
on the right side.

You can execute arbitrary Python code in the stack frames and there
are some extra helpers available for introspection:

dump() shows all variables in the frame dump(obj) dumps all that's
known about the object Brought to you by DON'T PANIC, your friendly
Werkzeug powered traceback interpreter.
```

My code is the following, I looked for a long time without finding any problems:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


app = Flask(__name__)


ENV = 'dev'

if ENV == 'dev':
    app.debug = True
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://postgres:Gray@localhost/Phict'

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Feedback(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'feedback'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    comments = db.Column(db.Text())

    def __init__(self, comments):
        self.comments = comments



@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')





@app.route('/submit', methods=['POST'])
def submit():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comments = request.form['fileToUpload']
        
        data = Feedback(comments)
        db.session.add(data)
        db.session.commit()
            
            


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: The `submit` function doesn't return anything.  It must return something, even if it's just an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

as stated by **@snakecharmerb** in his comment above

> The submit function doesn't return anything. It must return something, even if it's just an empty string.

so in your case, you may need to return **redirection object** to the home page for e.g

```
@app.route('/submit', methods=['POST'])
def submit():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comments = request.form['fileToUpload']
        
        data = Feedback(comments)
        db.session.add(data)
        db.session.commit()

        #  you can add a 'flash' message and then redirect to the index page

        return redirect(url_for('index'))  # -- HERE --
```

refer to this topic https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.redirect